# Turn array in HTML data attribute into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to pass this array into a function:

```
[
['ib-marker1', -24.9256,-43.8994, 0],
['ib-marker2', -22.9556,-43.8994, 0]
]
```

The array needs to be embedded in the HTML, so I added it like so:

```
<div id="map" data-markers="[['ib-marker1', -24.9256,-43.8994, 0],['ib-marker2', -22.9556,-43.8994, 0]]">
```

Then I take that info and call my function:

```
var markers = $(this).find("#map").data("markers"); init(markers);
```

This is a Google Maps function. No marker is recognized. I gather it is because my markers variable contains a string, not a real array. I just can't figure out how to do it.

As a test, I tried passing the array directly through the variable (not in the data attribute) and it worked fine:

```
var pins = [['ib-marker1', -24.9256,-43.8994, 0],['ib-marker2',
-22.9556,-43.8994, 0]];
```

Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: `var markers = eval($(this).find("#map").data("markers"));`

Comment: avoid eval() and try JSON.parse() on the data-markers content

Comment: An HTML attribute is a string.  Your pins array is a javascript array, the are not the same.  You need to write code to parse the string to create the array with the data you want in it.

Comment: JSON.parse didn't work, but eval did! Why should I avoid eval()? Anyway, if you post this on an actual answer, I´ll accept it. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: If you can alter the syntax of your data parameter, such as replace the braces with a custom character that doesn't occur elsewhere, you could use `split` to make an array of your points as strings and then run `array.forEach` to further turn each element into a small nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering nobody posted the right answer as an actual answer, I'm posting dfsq and Ayyash's answers here. This actually did the trick:

```
var markers = eval($(this).find("#map").data("markers"));
```

Comment: `eval`-ing a user-accessible element data? A possible **attack** would be i.e: someone accessing or appending a  `#map` and modifying the `data-markers` on your page. Injecting into data a malicious JS string. Your code will than process that JS. How cool is that?

Comment: It's a good point. What would you suggest doing instead? @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

You must use **valid** JSON(not an object-literal), then jQuery may parse the data correctly via `.data("markers")`.

Valid JSON uses double-quotes to enclose strings(not single-quotes):

```
<div id="map" data-markers="[[&quot;ib-marker1&quot;,-24.9256,-43.8994,0],[&quot;ib-marker2&quot;,-22.9556,-43.8994,0]]"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnG4b/ (take a look into the console)